# Why won't my elements shrink when I use flex-shrink?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Ive just started working on the landing page project from the odin project, and I've come across this problem where the header text is overlapped by the "image" when I make the browser window smaller, and when I make it as small as it can go, it turns into a long vertical mess.

I added flex shrink to both hero and image, I expected it to shrink and keep the same kinda layout that I have set for it, but instead of doing that, it just piles up onto of each other, and for some reason the image goes to the bottom left corner.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background: #1f2937;
    color: #F9FAF8;
    font-size: 24px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 230px;
    padding-right: 230px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    max-height: 40px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

.headersecondarytext {
    color: #E5E7EB;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#headerlinkone {
    margin-left: auto;
}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.hero {
    display: flex;
    background: #1f2937;
    color: #F9FAF8;
    padding: 50px 10px;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    padding-left: 230px;
    padding-right: 230px;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}


.herotext {
    max-width: 400px;
}

.heromaintext {
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.herosecondarytext {
    color: #E5E7EB;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.photo {
    display: flex;
    background: gray;  
    padding: 50px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 370px;
    min-height: 100px;
    align-self: flex-end;
    position: relative;
    top: -200px;
    flex-shrink: 1;
}

button {
    align-self: flex-start;
    background: #3882f6;
    padding: 7px 25px;
    color: #F9FAF8;
    font-weight: 600;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        
        <h3>Header Logo</h3>
        <a href="#" id="headerlinkone"  class="headersecondarytext">Header Link one</a>
        <a href="#" class="headersecondarytext">Header Link two</a>
        <a href="#" class="headersecondarytext">Header Link three</a>
    </div>
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="herotext">
            <div class="heromaintext">This Website Is Awesome</div>
            <div class="herosubtext">This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title. It's a smaller font and the color is lower
            contrast</div></div>
            <div class="button"><button>Sign up</button></div>
            <div class="photo">This is a placeholder for an image</div>
        
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `flex-shrink` needs to be used with `flex-basis`. So you need to specify a base size with `flex-basis`.

The properties `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis` need to be applied directly on the items, not in the container.

For example:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}

.item_type_1 {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-shrink: 2;
}

.item_type_2 {
    flex-basis: 200px;
    flex-shrink: 6;
}
```

With the property `flex-grow` you would indicate a growth factor.